# How not have page numbers when there is \maketitle

Tags: header-footer, titles, page-numbering

After translating in pdflatex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}   %  no page number

\begin{document}

\title{Article name}
\author{Author}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

the first page is numbered.

How do I remove the numbering? Or is there another tool for having no page numbers?

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}` just after `\maketitle`.

Comment: Bernard Thank you - it works. Do you know why it is not ok otherwise?

Comment: Thre way LaTeX builds the page, I guess. But I don't know enough internal details to explain. Andrew Swann's explanation just below seems to be  the right one.

Answer (score 2):

In `artcile.cls` without the `titlepage` option, the definition of `\maketitle` contains

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
```

You can discover this by issuing `\show\maketitle` and looking the `.log` file, but the output is quite long.

This means that either you need to change the `plain` layout, or much simpler, you need to issue `\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\maketitle` has had effect, but before the page ends.
In your example, the latter is sufficient.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}   %  no page number

\begin{document}

\title{Article name}
\author{Author}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

If you had used the `titlepage` option then there would have been no page number.

Note that other places where `\thispagestyle{plain}` in `article.cls` is issued is on the first page of an index if you have one.

See [Page number on Index page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140609/15925) for defining the `plain` page style.